Creating a generic mapper method for a generic list used in pagination object
I have been following a tutorial to add pagination to a web api. I have a class called ReviewSummaryPOCO  which has my db results binded to it from Dappper as a IEnumerable and I pass this to a PaginationList which keeps information about pagination. I have a mapper class which I keep all my various mapper helpers to translate my POCOs to my DTOs.
Since my pagination class uses generics since various objects bind into it I am struggling how to make a mapper method for this and also how to even access the list inside the PageinationList class.
My pagination model:
public class PaginationList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public bool HasPrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
    public bool HasNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;
    public PaginationList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = count;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        AddRange(items);
    }
    public static PaginationList<T> ToPagedList(ICollection<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = source.Count();
        var items = source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return new PaginationList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
}

My repository looks as follows:
        public async Task<PaginationList<ReviewSummaryPOCO>> GetAllAsync(PaginationRequestDTO request)
    {
        using(var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
        {
            var offset = (request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize;

            string sql = @"
            SELECT COUNT(0) [Count] FROM (select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0001_Browse()) as TMP;
            select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0001_Browse() order by MMCID Desc OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;";
            
            var multiQuery =  await connection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, new {offset, request.PageSize});
            var totalRowCount = multiQuery.Read<int>().Single();
            var gridDataRows = multiQuery.Read<ReviewSummaryPOCO>().ToList();

            return PaginationList<ReviewSummaryPOCO>.ToPagedList(gridDataRows, request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);
        }     
    }

I was doing a manual mapping as shown:
        public async Task<PaginationList<ReviewSummaryDTO>> GetAllAsync(PaginationRequestDTO request)
    {
        var paginationListPOCO = await _reviewSummaryRepository.GetAllAsync(request);
        var paginationListDTO = _mapper.Map<ReviewSummaryDTO>(paginationListPOCO);

        return paginationListDTO;
    }

An example of a mapper method from my mapper class is as follows:
        public async Task<List<DocumentDTO>> MapAsync(IEnumerable<DocumentPOCO> documentsPOCO)
    {
        if(documentsPOCO is null)
        {
         return new List<DocumentDTO>();
        }

        var documentsDTO = new List<DocumentDTO>();
        
        var mapTask = documentsPOCO.Select(async document => {
            documentsDTO.Add(await MapAsync(document));
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(mapTask);

        return documentsDTO;
    }

    public DocumentDTO Map(DocumentPOCO documentPOCO)
    {
        var documentDTO = new DocumentDTO{
            Mmcid = documentPOCO.MMCID,
            FilenameAtUpload = documentPOCO.FILENAME_AT_UPLOAD,
            DocGroupTypeDd = documentPOCO.DOC_GROUP_TYPE_DD,
            WhenUploaded = documentPOCO.WHEN_UPLOADED,
            DmcpBoxId = documentPOCO.DMCP_BOX_ID,
            DmcpTabId = documentPOCO.DMCP_TAB_ID,
            DmcpDocumentPath = documentPOCO.DMCP_DOCUMENT_PATH,
            OactDocumentPath = documentPOCO.DOCUMENT_PATH,
            Filename = documentPOCO.DOCUMENT_FILENAME
        };

        return documentDTO;
    }


Could you please share the ReviewSummaryDTO and ReviewSummaryPOCO makeup and which list you want to also query when doing the mapping ? DocumentDTO?
